# UIView Autoresizing

Tags: ios, uiview, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I could easily spend hours (if not days) trying to figure this out (I'm already several hours into it!!!)

I have a UIView that contains subviews (see attached graphic) and is built before it is even added as a subview to anything.

[image]

At a certain point in time, I add it as a subview view to a UITableViewCell. I call

```
[tableViewCell.contentView addSubview:mySubview]
    //....
[mySubview setBounds:tableViewCell.contentView.bounds]
```

and when I init my subview I have:

```
[self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES]
```

From my graphic, you can see I am assuming that only the width changes. What do I have to do to get the right hand subview of mySubview to expand to the full width while maintaining it's original origin?

I could easily be approaching this all wrong in my thinking and I welcome any suggestions!

**EDIT**
Thanks very much for your assistance, Khanh Nguyen

So, as I previously stated, when I init v1, (and, by definition v2) I don't know the dimensions of v1.

When I do know the bounds I want to place v1 in I am assuming I can do something like this:

```
[v1 setBounds:(some CGRECT)];
v2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

or C I just set the autoresizingMask on v2 as soon as I instantiate it (when I still don't know the dimensions of v1)?

Comment: Some questions: 1. Are you using autolayout? 2.Are you sure that you aren't using autolayout?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andrea. All I can tell you is that I am not using storyboard of xib files (everything is being done programmatically) and I haven't declared anywhere in my code to use (or not use) autolayout.

Comment: HAve you set the autoresingmask of the hosted view (mySubview)?

Comment: @Andrea, nope, what you see in my original post regarding autoresizing is all I have set.

Comment: T Just try to add before adding mySubviews this line mySubview.autoresingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a view `v1`, its subview `v2` and you want `v2` to have fixed left edge, while its width changes when `v1` is resized (i.e. distance between `v1`'s right edge and `v2`'s right edge is constant), use this:

```
v2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

For Swift:

```
v2.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin]
```

By default, `autoresizesSubviews` is YES. You don't need to set it.

**EDIT**

Every view has dimensions, even if you don't know it (just do an `NSLog` if you want to know it). If the view has just been init'ed, its dimensions are likely (0, 0). `autoresizesSubviews` works *even in that case*, as long as you know how much spacing you need between the subview and the superview.

For example, you want `v2` is 10px from `v1` for left margin and 20px for right margin, the following will do

```
// v1 has been initialized, and its dimensions are unknown (to you)
// It's probably (0, 0), but that doesn't matter
// 30px = 10px + 20px
v2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, v1.bounds.size.width - 30, 100);
v2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Note the third line, `v2.frame` will be set to some negative numbers if `v1` has zero size initially, but latter when `v1`'s frame is set to its proper size (either by you or `UITableViewCell`), `v2` will resize accordingly (because of the autoresizing constraint) and become exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: This may help, not sure yet. What I am doing, is initWithFrame on subView v2 in some unknown context of v1. When I finally come along and do a setBounds on v1, should v2 automatically become wider? Keep in mind, I did an initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110,10,super.frame.size.width,super.frame.size.height) before super's frame was defined.

Comment: You need to know the exact size of `v1` and `v2` the moment this line is called. After that line, changes to `v1`'s width will propagates to `v2`.